# Jquery opens dialog 3 times

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a button which call a function, this function gets a template into a Jquery dialog. The dialog opens three time in every call, but I don't know why.

I inspected the number of button click method, and the number of gets with alerts and console.log
The button click runs once as well.

What's the problem with my code? Thanks!

```
function egytalalatszerkeszt(talalatid, tomb, felado){
    alert("Something first"); //Run once

    $.get("templates/dokszerkeszttemp.php", function(visszatemp){
        alert("Something get"); //Run once
        var dialog = $().add(visszatemp);
        $.each(tomb, function(idx, item){
            console.log(tomb); //Logged once
            $(dialog).dialog({
                title: ("Title"),
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                width: 1000,
                height: 520,
                modal:true,
                open: function(){
                    alert("dialog opened"); //Run 3 times
                    ...
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what data in `tomb`?

Comment: looks like you have three items in tomb?

Comment: No, I have about 20 items, in this array.

Comment: Well, I try with other array elements, but runs 3 times again. (with static data)
I tried without $.each, but runs 3 times again.

I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the root problem. I had a little script inside the called template. This script caused the problem.